# Changing the font for labels in my project

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

My client wants me to change the label font to "Interstate-bold". I have installed the font. I dragged the font to the resource folder in Xcode and added it to the Info.plist but it is not supported yet. What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

I think you followed correct steps to apply this fonts in app.

You can check exact name of font supported, by following way:

NSArray *fonts = [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:@"interstate"];

NSLog this fonts array and give that exact name in the fontName parameter llike this

[UIFont fontWithName:@"Interstate-Bold" size:14.0];

I am getting this, plz check at ur end.

Answer (score 1):

So as you say you have:

1. added asset
2. in plist: Fonts provided by application, then name of the font  FSAlbert.otf [*.otf]
3. placing the used name to your label:

the name of the font is not the same as the name you put on your label is different,

```
self.myLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"FS Albert" size:14];
```

look what is the name of that font for example in photo shop [or font book], and that would be the name for your label.font

Answer (score 0):

Check in font book the name of the font.

Most probably the font name in the file name doesn't matches what is required to be given in iOS app.

So check what is the font name in font book and put it the app.

Comment: thanks for replying me.. i am using the font name as per given xib name